# how to bring java swing with other platform?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I am trying to run my application in different platform. the application use may input and output. i put this files with classes that are used. for the path i put

```
public static String getPath() {
        String decodedPath = null;
        try {
            String path = InstallApk.class.getProtectionDomain()
                    .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
            // URLDecoder decoder = new URLDecoder();
            decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return decodedPath;
    }
```

but when i am trying to test my jar with other system or other position from usb for exemple. i haven't the write path but a wrong one.